# Cannot find app-context.xml

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, netbeans

this is the next installment of "As the JAVA error turns".

So I have this app and it compiles fine. I read a thread here and moved my app-context.xml and application-context.xml into a SOURCES folder UNDER the main directory NOT inside the Web-Inf/ directory.

I get this error:

```
[                     Thread-22] ContextLoader                  ERROR      Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException     parsing XML document from class path resource [app-context.xml]; nested     exception is java.io.FileNotFoun
dException: class path resource [app-context.xml] cannot be opened because     it does not exist
```

Here's my WEB.XML file section for this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml classpath:app-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>applicationContextLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/source/applicationContext.xml classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

So that's the only error and the app will not start in Apache Tomcat 7.x.  Any thoughts or words of wisdom? Please?

**UPDATE!**

```
[Thread-18] ContextLoader ERROR Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 14 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/source/app-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 63; The prefix "context" for element "context:component-scan" is not bound.
```

Here's the app-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
   default-autowire="byName">

<tx:annotation-driven classpath="/Web Pages/" />

<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to
     configure as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ccur.mdimgmtsys" />


<!-- Drives transactions using local JPA APIs -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="forceDatabase" />
 </bean>

 <bean
 class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPost
 Processor" />

<bean id="forceService" class="com.force.sdk.connector.ForceServiceConnector">
    <property name="connectionName" value="forceDatabase"/>
</bean>

    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
p:url="${jdbc.url}"
p:username="${jdbc.username}"
p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

<!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->


</beans>
```

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include the context namespace (example from a private project):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">
```

(note: xmlns:context="..." and afterwards xsi:schemaLocation="... http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd"

I have neither checked your version of spring nor the latest, but some time ago this one worked for me ;)
Please update it to your required version.